# Calling a function from twig template where a request is made to the database then trying to return it as an array

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

Im busy working on a certain test where I need to call a variable from the database with two parameters (category_id and archetype_id). Im new with symfony and I can't figure out how to return an array from my controller function. It either comes back as "{[]}" or it says it can only be a string.

I've tried using JsonResponse, but im not sure why I recieve this as a string in my twig template.

in my twig template:

```
{% set variable = render(controller('App\\Controller\\TestController::getFromDatabase', {'c': 1 , 'a': 12 })) %}
{{ dump variable }}
```

in my controller:

```
public function getFromDatabase(int $c, int $a)
    {
        $variables = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App\Entity\Variables')->findBy(['category_id' => $c, 'archetype_id' => $a]);
        return new JsonResponse($variables);
    }
```

[how the data is show, as a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHI1R.png)

The frustrating thing is that I know how to do this with just php and vanilla coding and I haven't been able to wrapped my head around Symfony (seems like there are more steps than usual?)

[this is what i want to request from my database as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJEwG.png)

Can anyone tell me how to pass an array from a function to my twig template when called for? I've found a weird work around for another array I needed which looked like this, but I dont think this is the proper way, here i just made the string I got into an array:

```
{% set question1 = render(controller('App\\Controller\\TestController::randomNumberSet', {'amount': (ArchetypeCombi[randomNumbers[q]].c1)|length-1 })) %}
                        {% set question1 = question1|replace({'[': ''}) %}
                        {% set question1 = question1|replace({']': ''}) %}
                        {% set question1 = question1|split(',') %}
```

I would appreciate the help ;)

Comment: Does your entity have public properties? If not you should implement [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely not render a controller method from Twig.
Consider creating a custom [Twig Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) instead.

Assuming `autowire` is enabled and you are using the default `services.yaml` configuration, the following should work fine. Otherwise, you might want to manually register your class as a service, tag it with `twig.extension` and define the `EntityManager` as a parameter.

```
// src/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace App\Twig;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;
use App\Entity\Variables;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
  private $entityManager;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
  {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
  }

  public function getFunctions()
  {
    return [
      new TwigFunction('getVariables', [$this, 'getVariables'])
    ];
  }

  public function getVariables(int $categoryId, int $archetypeId)
  {
    $parameters = ['category_id' => $categoryId, 'archetype_id' => $archetypeId];
    $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Variables::class);
    return $repository->findBy($parameters);
  }
}
```

Then call your custom Twig function in your template

```
{% set variables = getVariables(1, 12) %}
{{ dump(variables) }}
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to write thank you comments, but this makes a lot more sense to me now, so thank you.